# How can I get Python exit code from a bash script?

Tags: python, bash, exit

Hello I am struggling to get the python return code from my script called in a bash script. See as follows:

toto.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    OK = myTest()

    if(OK):
        print("Test was successful. Error code: 0")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("Test failed. Error code: 1")
        sys.exit(1)
```

in test.sh:

```
python toto.py
echo "After calling toto.py"
```

If my python script returns sys.exit(0), the bash script continues and print "After calling toto.py". But if my python script ends by sys.exit(1), the bash script ends and does not continue. I can see in the console that the correct exit code is returned by calling `echo $?` and prints 1.
I did not expect the python sys.exit() function to also exit my bash script.
Should I use "return" keyword then?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, the `echo` is always shown. As expected.

Comment: What happens if you put "set +e" at the start of the test script?

Comment: Yes I just figured it out, the script was starting with set -e. Removing it or replacing it by set +e solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your shell script, do this:-

```
python toto.py
echo $?
```